# Запуск функции в golang в определённое время

Tags: golang, время, datetime

Как в *golang* запустить функцию в определённое время?

Мне нужно запустить функцию `myfunc`, например, в 00:00. Как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте про планировщик [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Намного правильнее будет, и определённо прозрачнее, чем то, что ниже предлагают.

Comment: @AlexBelyaev, я ничего не предлагаю, я отвечаю на вопрос. Тем более все зависит от задачи; если функция должна запускаться в контексте работающего приложения и работать с его данными, вряд ли cron будет удобнее. В общем без телепатических возможностей сказать, что "прозрачнее" для стоящей перед топикстартером задачи, сказать что-то вряд ли можно.

Comment: Про телепатию соглашусь: то есть Вы ответили, как Вы сами поняли, не поинтересовавшись у ТС, что же ему на самом деле надо? :) Ладно, Ваша позиция мне ясна, флудить больше не будем.

Comment: @AlexBelyaev, да нет, я прочел задачу, и там чётко и однозначно написано, "как в golang запустить функцию в определённое время", именно об этом и был мой ответ. После, да, когда уточнилось, что нужно запускать раз в сутки, тогда уже закрались сомнения. P.S. И вам мир :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например вот так:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

// Описание формата времени.
const timeLayout = "Jan 2, 2006 15:04:05 MST"

// Вызов переданной функции в указанное время.
func callAt(callTime string, f func()) error {
    // Разбираем время запуска.
    ctime, err := time.Parse(timeLayout, callTime)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Вычисляем временной промежуток до запуска.
    duration := ctime.Sub(time.Now())

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(duration)
        f()
    }()

    return nil
}

// Ваша функция.
func myfunc() {
    fmt.Printf("+ %v\n", time.Now())
}

// Пример использования.
func main() {
    err := callAt("Jul 17, 2015 00:00:00 MSK", myfunc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    // Эмуляция дальнейшей работы программы.
    time.Sleep(time.Hour * 24)
}
```

Собственно, способов много, например можно использовать `time.After`, которая по прошествии указанного промежутка времени пошлет в канал сообщение. Главный вопрос тут -- в вычислении этого самого промежутка; один из возможных вариантов я и привел.

**Обновление**: вот вариант для каждодневного запуска:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

// Вызов переданной функции раз в сутки в указанное время.
func callAt(hour, min, sec int, f func()) error {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("Local")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Вычисляем время первого запуска.
    now := time.Now().Local()
    firstCallTime := time.Date(
        now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), hour, min, sec, 0, loc)
    if firstCallTime.Before(now) {
        // Если получилось время раньше текущего, прибавляем сутки.
        firstCallTime = firstCallTime.Add(time.Hour * 24)
    }

    // Вычисляем временной промежуток до запуска.
    duration := firstCallTime.Sub(time.Now().Local())

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(duration)
        for {
            f()
            // Следующий запуск через сутки.
            time.Sleep(time.Hour * 24)
        }
    }()

    return nil
}

// Ваша функция.
func myfunc() {
    fmt.Printf("+ %v\n", time.Now())
}

// Пример использования.
func main() {
    err := callAt(0, 0, 0, myfunc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    // Эмуляция дальнейшей работы программы.
    time.Sleep(time.Hour * 24)
}
```

Comment: А если каждый день в 00 часов? - Просто запустить себя саму или другой механизм есть?

Comment: Ещё вопрос. Когда 1 раз в день будет происходить "подчистка" данных в опред время- норм. Я думаю создать в проекте для экзаменов событие окончания экзамена для студентов. И вот когда наступит это время, то запустить определённую функцию. Нормально будет, если скажем будет в системе 100  текущих (незавершённых) экзаменов (т.е. соответственно +100 горутин) и они будут ждать своего часа- не будет ли это подгружать приложение?

Comment: На другом форуме предлагают cron

Comment: Добавил вариант для каждодневного запуска.

Comment: Пусть хоть 1000 горутин будут висеть в sleep, подгружать приложение это не будет.

Comment: Разумеется для подобных задач можно использовать cron, и только вам виднее, что использовать в вашей задаче удобнее. Вы в изначальном вопросе спросили о Go, я вам ответил.

Comment: Вы меня простите, но Вы предлагаете топикстартеру какой-то адъ. ТС задаёт вопрос на том уровне, который ему на данный момент доступен -- он знает лишь то, что пишет софтину на Go, и что ему необходимо её запускать по расписанию. О "лучших практиках" он не знает и, вероятно, не задумывался даже, что такие задачи решают сторонними утилитами. Наша работа -- порой додумывать за человека, направить его, а не как можно быстрее накодить "чтобы было". Имхо.

Comment: @AlexBelyaev, ответил к вашему комментарию к вопросу. А касательно уровня топикстартера, посмотрев его вопросы по Go, я бы, без обид, посоветовал ему подучить язык и пока не писать никаких "софтин" на нем.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки и наставления- без форумов конечно-было бы очень сложно. Очень на многие вопросы здесь нахожу ответы. Я изучаю go чуть полутора месяцев- конечно ещё ничего не знаю...но планы...планы- серъёзные! Сделаю приложение-дам вам ссылку...посмотрите. То, что задумал-не на многих сайтах вообще реализовано,хотя можно было-бы. Вот и ищу варианты, как реализовать задуманное не через жж..а что б нормально работало

Comment: Вместо time.Sleep() надо использовать  <-time.After(time.Second